# Moving Graphics Smoothly Rather Than Skipping in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, repaint

I was practicing moving graphics in Java and I seem to be coming to a problem. What I drew right now is 2 alien faces. At the moment my program is set up to move the faces 1 step at a time in a certain direction based on user input. What I would like to do is have the alien faces move from point A to point B. For example, right now it moves 1 step at a time because I have the parts of the faces increase by 1 on it's x and y. My thoughts were to start a loop before the method MoveHorizontal(), that way it would run so many times and I would have a smooth transition from one point to another. It's not working like that for me though. It would skip from where it started to where the loops ends rather than 1 step at a time. So my question is, how would I be able to do that? lol. Thank you.

```
//First Class
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AlienFace
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String userInput;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(700, 700);
       frame.setTitle("An Alien Face");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


       FaceComponent component = new FaceComponent();
       frame.add(component);

       frame.setVisible(true);

       System.out.println("Which direction would you like the Alien faces to move? ");
       System.out.print("H/h for horizontally, V/v for vertically, D/d for diagonally, or Q/q to quit: ");
       userInput = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println(userInput);

       while (!userInput.equals("q") || !userInput.equals("Q"))
       {
           System.out.println("Which direction would you like the Alien faces to move? ");
           System.out.print("H/h for horizontally, V/v for vertically, D/d for diagonally, or Q/q to quit: ");
           userInput = input.nextLine();

           if (userInput.equals("H") || userInput.equals("h"))
           {
               component.MoveHorizontal();
               frame.repaint();
           }



           if (userInput.equals("V") || userInput.equals("v"))
           {
               component.MoveVertical();
               frame.repaint();
           }

           if (userInput.equals("D") || userInput.equals("d"))
           {
               component.MoveDiagonal();
               frame.repaint();
           }
       }

       if (userInput.equals("q") || userInput.equals("Q"))
       {
           frame.setVisible(false);
       }
   }
```

}

```
//Second Class
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class FaceComponent extends JComponent
{
    int head2X = 5;
    int head2Y = 10;
    int head3X = 105;
    int head3Y = 115;
    int eye2X = 25;
    int eye2Y = 75;
    int eye3X = 125;
    int eye3Y = 175;
    int mouth2X1 = 30;
    int mouth2Y1 = 110;
    int mouth3X1 = 130;
    int mouth3Y1 = 210;
    int mouth2X2 = 80;
    int mouth2Y2 = 110;
    int mouth3X2 = 180;
    int mouth3Y2 = 210;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(head2X, head2Y, 100, 150);
    g2.draw(head);

    Ellipse2D.Double head1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(head3X, head3Y, 100, 150);
    g3.draw(head1);

    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(eye2X, eye2Y, 15, 15);
    g2.fill(eye);
    eye.translate(50, 0);
    g2.fill(eye);

    g3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Rectangle eye1 = new Rectangle(eye3X, eye3Y, 15, 15);
    g3.fill(eye1);
    eye1.translate(50, 0);
    g3.fill(eye1);

    Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(mouth2X1, mouth2Y1, mouth2X2, mouth2Y2);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(mouth);

    Line2D.Double mouth1 = new Line2D.Double(mouth3X1, mouth3Y1, mouth3X2, mouth3Y2);
    g3.setColor(Color.RED);
    g3.draw(mouth1);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.drawString("Hello, World!", 5, 175);
}

public void MoveHorizontal()
{
    head2X++;
    head3X++;
    eye2X++;
    eye3X++;
    mouth2X1++;
    mouth3X1++;
    mouth2X2++;
    mouth3X2++;

}

public void MoveVertical()
{
    head2Y++;
    head3Y++;
    eye2Y++;
    eye3Y++;
    mouth2Y1++;
    mouth3Y1++;
    mouth2Y2++;
    mouth3Y2++;
}

public void MoveDiagonal()
{
    head2X++;
    head3X++;
    eye2X++;
    eye3X++;
    mouth2X1++;
    mouth3X1++;
    mouth2X2++;
    mouth3X2++;
    head2Y++;
    head3Y++;
    eye2Y++;
    eye3Y++;
    mouth2Y1++;
    mouth3Y1++;
    mouth2Y2++;
    mouth3Y2++;
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to better understand how painting works.  GUIs don't work the same way as procedural (console based) programs might, they are event driven, something happens and you respond to it, you're going to have to change the way you're gathering input from the user to better suit that methodology

Comment: It's also not the frame that needs repainting